# How to detect dependency convergence violations between *independent* projects using maven enforcer plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management, maven-enforcer-plugin

When running [dependency convergence with the maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html), we can easily detect that a certain project transitively depends on 2 different versions of the same artifact.

But consider a large group that is writing plugins for the same system. And consider 2 teams in this group.

One team is developing plugin A and has the following dependency chain:
A -> B -> C (v 1.1)

the other team develops plugin X and has the following dependency chain:
X -> Y -> C (v 2.0)

Projects A and X are completely independent but in in production, both plugins are deployed and there is a collision. Although both teams share CI, the enforcer plugin does not detect this collision since collisions are detected only if they share a common ancestor.

(for example, if A also had: A -> D -> C (v 1.4), this would have been detected).

It seems that the solution is to define a 3rd 'super module' that will aggregate A and X and feed it to the enforcer plugin. I am having trouble with this:

I defined such a module. Added A and X as dependencies (of type 'pom') but when I execute the enforcer, it does not detect the collisions! It is as if the super pom fails to 'absorb' the transitive dependencies.

What am I missing here?

I am using maven 3.0.4.

---

A more concrete illustration:

[This link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29936928/2%20projecrs.zip) contains 2 independent projects. One has a dependency on *org.opensaml:opensaml:2.2.0* and the other on *org.apache.solr:solr-core:4.10.0*. Trouble is that the former depends on *commons-lang:commons-lang:2.1* while the later depends on *commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6*.

Consequently both of these jars appear in the classpath of the final application, which has the potential to break either of the dependencies.

[I tried creating another project that aggregates both 'roots'](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29936928/withsuper.zip) , but the enforcer plugin did not detect the collision.

This is the command line I am using: *mvn enforcer:enforce validate*

Comment: Can you create and example setup which reproduce this behaviour and what you expect.

Comment: @khmarbaise, added a supplement to the question. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know much about the enforcer plugin but it may be worth the try to create a "dummy" Maven project declaring the independent projects as its modules and run the plugin on the dummy project to have your "Modules" (independent Projects) analyzed for dependency convergence.

Comment: You may be hitting a peculiarity of the enforcer plugin: It runs in the `validate` phase, but some of the actual checks are merely scheduled to be run in a later phase (`compile`, typically, this may depend on the rule). The question isn't clear on what rules exactly you invoke so it is incomplete and cannot be answered as it is.